# C++17 class template deduction const-ness

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, class-template

I am attempting to use the new c++17 class template deduction and it all seems to work fine until I apply const. This is a small example of the trouble I'm facing:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct X
{
    T _data;

    X(void) = default;
    X(T && data) : _data{ data } {}

    constexpr bool const_x(void) { return false; }
    constexpr bool const_x(void) const { return true; }
};

template <typename T>
X(T &&) -> X<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

int main(void)
{
    X<int> a;
    const X<int> b{};

    X c{ 10 };
    const X d{ 10 };

    static_assert(!a.const_x());
    static_assert(b.const_x());

    static_assert(!c.const_x());
    static_assert(d.const_x()); // assert fails
}
```

it appears that when a const X is deducing its types, the const-ness is not carried through. I know this is possible:

```
template <typename T>
X(T &&) -> const X<std::remove_reference_t<X>>;
```

but this would make every deduced type const X.

If anyone has any information or help, it would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**  I am using GCC-7.1.0

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/kRdTpJ  clang trunk has no problem with your code. gcc trunk also has no issues: https://godbolt.org/g/TpneVq  looks like just a compiler bug. Presumably you were trying with gcc 7.1?  https://godbolt.org/g/j6W3dB (fails on that line)

Comment: Do you have any errors when compiling? Or only during execution?

Comment: @Fenixrw it's a static assert that's failing -- that's only a compile-time issue

Comment: @xaxxon does this fully compile on clang?

Comment: @FletcherBlight i posted the link...Here's the link with the "link"  option turned on.. https://godbolt.org/g/qm77Mx

Comment: @xaxxon thankyou for that, it does appear to be a compiler bug then

Comment: C++17 support is still sketchy (7/2017) on all released compilers.   Stick with '14 if you want stability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a compiler bug - specifically [gcc bug 80990](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80990). There are two separate parts here - the deduction, and the `const`. The declaration:

```
const X d{ 10 };
```

will first perform class template argument deduction to pick which `X` specialization `d` is (so `X<int>` due to the deduction guide), and then the `const` is added on top of that (so `X<int> const`).

---

Note also that this:

```
template <typename T>
X(T &&) -> const X<std::remove_reference_t<X>>;
```

is ill-formed. You cannot use cv-qualifiers there.